# I need a circuit able to calculate Vmax-Vmin of a squarewave

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, square

As already written in the title, I need to evaluate the voltage excursion of a certain signal. Vmax and Vmin could be both positive and negative (therefore two peak detection circuits cannot be used, i think), so i ask a possible solution.

P.S. A comparator cannot be used because the squarewave amplitudes can change, hence its main value isn't fixed.

Thank you.

edit: Clk signal frequency (squarewave) = 10kHz (clk peaks 0-5V, just sufficients to overcome the ideal MOS's voltage threshold), the circuit provides a p-2-p voltage proportional to the difference of the input capacitances values (in the case of this simulation -> ((110pF-10pF)/10pF = 10, that's equal to Vmax-Vmin ~ 12 - 2 = 10 .)

[C-2-V Converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2THXl.png)

Comment: You need to provide some details .....otherwise folks just have to guess. What is the peak to peak amplitude of your signal, and to what accuracy do you need to know the value?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question! My circuit is an op-amp conf with a capacitor sensor as input. The output is a squarewave, which p-2-p value changes according to the capacitance one. The accuracy needed is of the order of tenth of mV, with a max p-2-p value of +-15V (saturation voltages of OP-AMP)

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the details needed to answer it. The best way to describe a circuit is with a schematic. Click the schematic icon to open the built-in schematic editor when editing your question.

Comment: Also, be sure to tell us what is the square wave frequency, and how quickly can the amplitude change.

Comment: One other important detail is whether the solution is to be digital or analog. e.g., Do you want a voltage proportional to the p-p signal?

Comment: Apologize, I hope to entirely describe my problem now. An analog value is just sufficient. I haven't any significant limitation about the transient time of the squarewave.

Comment: Even with the edits, this question still needs some clarification.  You also say that you need 0.1mV accuracy, but an analog output is sufficient... these two statements don't quite make sense together.  Also, the speed at which the capacitance can change is relevant - do you need a different Vpp measurement at every clock cycle, or can you average over 10 clock cycles, or 1000?  Do you truly want an analog output, or will you be digitizing it later anyway?

Comment: I want to emphasize @Selvek's excellent points. Note also that \$100\:\mu\text{V}\$ within a dynamic range of \$30\:\text{V}\$ (which you claim) means about 3 ppm. Also, you have "information" about when to take measurements since you have clocks available that inform you about some important "moments" where sampling makes more sense. Any answer that's worth a darn will use this a priori knowledge, I believe.

Comment: I also want to add something to the term "accuracy" here. You can buy parts with "initial accuracy" ratings. But that's hardly useful for an instrument. There is temperature and time variations (air conditioner turns on and off, night vs daytime, long term drift, etc) which pretty much require calibration procedures traceable to NIST or DIN or to some standard if you want accuracy. If you are looking for precision, that's also valid but it is a different matter. I'd like to see your thoughts on this matter.

Comment: I hope to clarify everything with this comment. The squarewave in output has the same frequency of the clk (100k) and i need to make a real-time average of a single clock cycle in order to monitor how the sensor capacitance continuously changes, even though the latter changes very slow (several decades of clock cycles spent before significant capacitance changes, although).

Comment: I wrote "analogue is just sufficient" because i don't deprive myself to adopt a digital solution for my problem. Of course if you would to suggest me a low-pass filter, the time constant should be suitable with the clock period of the signal (10 um).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"therefore two peak detection circuits cannot be used, i think"

Of course they can. The trick is to pick your reference points as something other than ground. Use a negative peak detector which detects the peaks below a reference which is higher than the expected maximum, and a positive peak detector which is referenced to a level below the expected minimum. Both will now work over the desired signal range, and a difference amplifier fed by the two peak detectors will give the desired signal.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a 16bit ADC, with 0--5volt input range. 5v/65,000 = 80 microVolts quantization.